# When I do division in Java, I lose my decimal, how to show it?

Tags: java

when I do this

```
    double money = 2.3452;
    DecimalFormat decFor = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
    System.out.println(decFor.format(money));
```

### I get this output: 2.35

But when I do this

```
    double money = 1/8;
    DecimalFormat decFor = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
    System.out.println(decFor.format(money));
```

I get: 0.00

How to make Java to show you 0.12 instead of 0.00?

Answer (score 5):

Do this:

```
double money = 1.0 / 8;
```

The problem is that you are taking the integer, 1 and dividing it by an integer, 8.  Java then uses integer math, which truncates to 0.  If you use 1.0 explicitly, then it will use floating point division.

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast to double. In integer division the fractional part of the result is thrown away.

```
double money = (double)1/8;
DecimalFormat decFor = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
System.out.println(decFor.format(money));
```